# Unable to see typescript template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5, typescript1.8

When I click on Add new file in VS I didn't see typescript template in VS2015.

I have installed typescript also externally from [Microsoft Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) and restarted VS and even system. I can see Typescript in Microsoft SDK's but still I'm not getting Typescript template in VS.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Did you find the solution?